# Helium - Installing backup manually

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

When I try restoring from a helium backup, it says restoring forever and does not complete, therefore I want to restore the backup manually by moving apk to their folders. The zip however only contains a `backup.json` file and a bunch of `com.identifier.name.ab` files with PNG for their icons. What is this ab extension? Can I restore manually? I did not encrypt the backup. I have root, if it is required.

Also note that I am using an unofficial build of cyanogenmod. My phone is an SM-G800F kminilte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file with the `.ab` extension is what you need for that (AB = Android Backup). You can restore it manually from your PC using `adb restore com.identifier.name.ab`. Requirement for that is the ADB installed on your computer; details on that can be found via the [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) – and if you don't want to install the entire Android SDK, take a special look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

---

Some notes from the comments moved up here:

- No, neither [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) nor [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) are restoring [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) backups (at least not as of this writing). Both use [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) for backups, which is a completely different concept using a completely different format.
- [TitaniumBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) can read both, ADB and Nandroid backups, and extract those parts from them you wish. I don't know if it can do a "full restore" from `.ab` backup files – but if those were single-app backups (like those created by Helium), I wouldn't be surprised.
- Yes, of course `adb restore` restores the app data from `.ab` files. That's what it's for :)
- caution, advertisement: For a batch backup of all your apps and data, as well as a batch restore, a device documentation, and more, take a look at my [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) (Android DEvice Backup And Report). Works on Linux and reportedly on Windows with Cygwin.

Comment: is that unconventional for an ab file to be named like that(like the questioner named it and like you do in your answer)?  for a moment there I thought adb restore can restore individual apps, though I see it can't it only restores the whole ab file, though his ab file was just the one app.

Comment: `.ab` indeed is the default extension used by `adb backup`. And yes, `adb restore` always restores the complete backup, no picking – but with `adb backup` you can choose what should be inside. Take e.g. a look at my tool [Adebar](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar) which makes use of that fact, a.o. creating scripts to backup all your apps each in its own backup file.